# Script is not sending an email upon running the code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this script to send an auto email when the date = current date then run but it is not sending the email i do not know why.

Your help will be much appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wxDa9D9a1wddqu9Fh4r3uZAX0m1NKNj2H7g_uS141-0/edit#gid=0

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Mysheet");
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(data)

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date();
    var sheetDate = new Date(row[1]);
    Sdate=Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0200','yyyy:MM:dd')
    SsheetDate=Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT+0200', 'yyyy:MM:dd')
    Logger.log(Sdate+' =? '+SsheetDate)
    if (Sdate == SsheetDate){
      var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
      var message = row[2];       // Second column
      var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
//      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
     Logger.log('SENT :'+emailAddress+'  '+subject+'  '+message)
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Upon running the code, the row 2's condition is passing so it should be sending the mail. What are you seeing in the logs for those 2 dates ?

Comment: But its not sending the emails. here is the execution log windows https://imgur.com/NnylGS3 it shows the email has been sent. then i used different emails problem was same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Mysheet");
  const startRow = 2;   
  const subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
  const vs = sh.getRange(startRow, 1, sh.getLastRow() - startRow + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach(row =>  {
    let dt = new Date();
    let dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
    let sdt = new Date(row[1]);
    let sdtv = new Date(sdt.getFullYear(),sdt.getMonth(),sdt.getDate()).valueOf();
    if (sdtv == dtv){
      MailApp.sendEmail(row[0], subject, row[2]);
    }    
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Cooper it works perfect now.